# Customized Hover in TH

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I have the cursor on the th with value "#" the text color shall be #f5f5f5. The remaining of th column shall not be affected.

Don't know how to do it.

Thanks

[image]

```css
**CSS**

.makeThisOpacity {
}
.makeThisOpacityaa {
    opacity: 0;
}
.makeThisOpacity > th:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        </style>
        <br>
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <tr class="makeThisOpacity">
                <th class="makeThisOpacityaa">#</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Username</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: do you require rest of the th values to change background color on hover?

Comment: Please take a look at the picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `opacity:1` will solved your issue.

```css
**CSS**

.makeThisOpacity {
}
.makeThisOpacityaa {
    opacity: 0;
}
.makeThisOpacity > th:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        </style>
        <br>
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <tr class="makeThisOpacity">
                <th class="makeThisOpacityaa">#</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Username</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

`color: black;` is for text color

`background-color: #f5f5f5;` is for background color

You do the all other things right

If you want to apply this style only for one th you should change your last selector to: `th.makeThisOpacityaa:hover`

Comment: If I understand correctly, just modify last selector to `th.makeThisOpacityaa:hover` - this limit your scope

Comment: I edit comment, check again `th.makeThisOpacityaa:hover`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6n1m9c14/ it works for me or I don't understand your problem. In 2nd case explain it more detailed

Comment: When you have the cursor on the TH "#", it shows. In my case I don't want the text "#" to display when you have the cursor on the TH "#".

Comment: And show this # when you don't have cursor on it? What text color you want to change on hover when you don't show anything?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not working because you applied `#f5f5f5` as a `background-color` not `color`, `background-color:` property will change the background color as name suggest. and `color` property will change the text color

Try this

```
.makeThisOpacity > th:hover {
    color: #f5f5f5;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: @HelloWorld note that `#f5f5f5` is almost `white` so it may not be visible on a white background.

Comment: I tried your code but the column name Firstname, Last name and username was turned into color "#f5f5f5" when you hover over them. I wa nt them to be black color.